# Securing Windows port with SSL for socket connection

Tags: sockets, security, ssl, ssl-certificate

I have a web app that makes requests to an external API running on a Windows machine via raw sockets. This is a third party program that only uses sockets. I want to make sure that the data being sent and received is secured.

Example:

My site https://example.com/order (hosted on AWS) opens a backend socket connection to 132.XXX.XXX.XXX:2913 and sends sensitive data back and forth. Am I correct in assuming that the SSL certificate for my website will not cover the data over the socket?

My initial thought was to bind a separate SSL certificate to port 2913 on the Windows machine, but I'm not sure if that is correct (or at least it did not work for me).

Steps I have taken:

1. Opened port 2913 on Windows machine
2. Created a self signed certificate using PowerShell (.pfx file)
3. Used netsh to bind the SSL cert to port 2913
4. Created cert and key files for connecting from my web client

*netsh http show sslcert* shows that the SSL cert is bound to that port, but I am still able to access the API without having to secure my socket connection from the web client.

Any idea on where I went wrong (if even on the right track) or other thoughts would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: It's unclear what is connected to what. Is example.com *your* website? Is the connection to 132.XXX.XXX.XXX:2913 occurring as a backend connection from example.com?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it James.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I correct in assuming that the SSL certificate for my website will not cover the data over the socket?

Yes, this is correct.

You will need to contact the provider of that API to request that they provide a SSL/TLS version of the API. There is no way for you to unilaterally apply encryption to the connection.